# Let $H \leq G$: prove that $K=\{x\in G:\exists n \in\Bbb{N},\,x^n\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$H$ is a subgroup of an abelian group $G$. We define

$$K = \{ x \in G : \exists n \in \Bbb{N}, x^n \in H\}.$$

How to prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ ?

Answer (score 2):

To show $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, we need to show $(i)$ $K$ is nonempty (which we will do my showing $e$, the identity in $G, H \in K$; $(ii)$ that  $K$ is closed under taking inverses; and $(iii)$ that $K$ is closed under the group operation.

I'll work through $(i), \;(ii)\;\;$ and help set up what you need to show $(iii)$.

---

(i) **Identity:**

- We know that since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, it contains $e$, the identity element of $G$. And $e\in G, e^n = e \in H$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

(ii) **Closure under Inverses**:

- Now we need to show that for every element in $x \in K$, $x^{-1} \in
     K$.
- Use the fact that if $x \in K,$ then $x^n \in H$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
  Let $x \in K,$ so x^{n} \in H$. Now  $x^n \in H \implies (x^{n})^{-1} \in H$, since $H$ is a subgroup, and therefore is closed under inverses. But $(x^n)^{-1} = x^{-n} = (x^{-1})^n \in H \implies x^{-1} \in K$.

(iii) **Closure under the group operation**:

- Then we need to show for any $x, y \in K, (x\circ y)^k \in K,$ for
  some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
- Use the facts that for $x, y \in K$, $x^n, y^m \in H$ for some $ n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. 
  So we need to show that $(x \circ y) \in K$ by showing $(x\circ y)^k \in H$, for some $k \in \mathbb N$. 
  Note that since $H$ is a subgroup, it is closed under the group operation, and since $x^n, y^m \in H$, so is $x^n\circ y^m \in H$.
- What can you say about $x^n\circ y^m \in H,$ knowing that $G$ is abelian? How can we use these facts to show $x \circ y \in K$?

Answer (score 2):

First do the case $H=0$, then $K$ is known as the torsion subgroup of $G$. In general, $K$ is the torsion subgroup of $G/H$ pulled back along the projection $G \twoheadrightarrow G/H$.

Comment: Ah! And within the same minute, +1.

Comment: I think that if I were taking a first course in group theory, and someone would tell me something like that I'd either think they are using fancy words to obscure the reasoning from me; or that they are showing off. Certainly by the time I was in my graduate years such answer makes a lot of sense. But to an undergraduate this answer is as useful as "Trivially."

Comment: Hopefully there are still people who read this and can learn something. Also in practice these kind of reduction arguments are of tremendous help. Or just as a first step, consider $H=0$, and then try to do the general case in the same way (or even deduce it from that by using quotient groups). I dislike the scattering of apparently isolated observations. Instead I always would like to point out that mathematics is kind of a "net".

Comment: @AsafKaragila There are lots of answers on this website which would qualify as obscure or fancy from the OP's perspective. I confess some of mine do, not many, since I'm not particularly smart or knowledgeable anyway. None of yours do? They're still legitimate. In this case, the OP might want to google torsion subgroup and learn a concept (whose definition is not that wild) related to his/her question.

Comment: @julien: I have no problem with the answer being obscure and less-helpful to the OP. I do have some issue with it being a single sentence saying "Oh, that's *this*". Because it really doesn't answer the question, it just gives the question an alternative formulation from the point of view of those unfamiliar with the terms. Giving a concrete answer **and** pointing out the abstraction would be a wonderful way of answering this question. But not a single line. Imagine yourself on the first day of freshman calculus and the TA spits "reductions" at you, how helpful is that? Not very much.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with you. But given that there are already more elementary answers available, I think it does not hurt to give a different perspective. When I was a student, I've faced several times this situation. Someone would throw at me a one-line argument involving mysterious concepts. Of course, I would look for another answer I could understand, but usually I would remember the sophisticated argument and save it for later. It helped a lot connecting more and more abstract concepts to more basic problems.

Answer (score 2):

It is the set of all elements $x\in G$ such that
$$
\overline{x}=xH
$$
has finite order in $G/H$.

In other words, if we denote
$$
\pi:G\longrightarrow G/H
$$
the canonical surjection, and if we set $L$ to be the set of all finite order elements in $G/H$, then
$$
K=\pi^{-1}(L).
$$
So it suffices to check that $\pi$ is a group homomorphism and that $L$ is a subgroup of $G/H$. Both are easy.

This is far from being the fastest way, but that's how I see it.

Comment: That's also how I see it. ;)

Comment: It’s a way that may not be available to the OP, however: the question is one that could well be asked before quotient groups are even introduced.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sure. But is it a problem to propose such an answer?

Comment: No, no problem; it may be useful to someone else later. My comment was at least partly intended as reassurance in case the OP found the answer puzzling.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, ok. So I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Just check the requirements for being a subgroup: show that $K$ is non-empty, closed under the group operation, and closed under taking inverses.

- Closure under the operation: If $x,y\in K$, then there are $m,n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x^m,y^n\in H$. Can you find from $m$ and $n$ a positive integer $k$ such that $(xy)^k\in H$? Use the fact that $G$ is Abelian.
- Closure under taking inverses: If $x\in K$, then there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x^n\in H$. Can you find a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $(x^{-1})^k\in H$?